# Using React and Electron - react-router error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

I just started learning how to make desktop apps with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) and I'm trying to use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) with Electron but I keep getting the error
`Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes`

**main.js**

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.on('closed', () => win = null);
})
```

**routes.js**

```
import App from './app';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import React from 'react';

const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </Router>
);
```

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} history={hashHistory}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf yes, I had to create a nodejs server for it to work, express to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

Didn't noticed. You are declaring your router in routes.js, then in index you are declaring another router passing routes as prop.

I think you should change your routes.js (you have to export your routes const).

routes:

```
import App from './app';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import React from 'react';

const routes = (
   <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Now you can import it in your index, and you should render directly your routes:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put history props in Router?

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
```

Comment: Yup, doesn't with any of the history for me. Thank you :)